An algebraic measure for checking optimal point, that works for graphical solution; and possibly for any # of dimensions (# of axes).
Have understood that the graphical approach for solving LPP, works till two variables (axes) case.
It is stated here, that the optimal point has the maximum distance from the origin. It states:

An optimum point always lies on one of the corners of the feasible region. How to find it? Place a ruler on the graph sheet, parallel to the objective function. Be sure to keep the orientation of this ruler fixed in space. We only need the direction of the straight line of the objective function. Now begin from the far corner of the graph and tend to slide it towards the origin.
If the goal is to minimize the objective function, find the point of contact of the ruler with the feasible region, which is the closest to the origin. This is the optimum point for minimizing the function.
If the goal is to maximize the objective function, find the point of contact of the ruler with the feasible region, which is the farthest from the origin. This is the optimum point for maximizing the function.

Hence, the measure for the optimum point can be the pythagorean distance, from the origin.
But, the same is not stated elsewhere, as a measure of finding the optimal point. 
Though, the measure of pythagorean distance should be usable for higher dimensional case too, i.e. $\geq 3$ dimensions.
Say, the below LPP, taken from the REA book, titled: The Operations Research Problem Solver, is following this measure:

A cabinet maker has $12$ units of wood & intends to build two different types of bookcases in $36$ hours. Model $1$ requires $3$ units of wood and $6$ hours of labor. Model $2$ requires $2$ units of wood and $8$ hours of labor.
The selling prices of the models are $\$90$ & $\$150$ respectively.
How many bookcases of each model should the cabinet maker assemble in order to maximize his revenue?
Construct a model to depict the situation and solve graphically to get an optimal solution.

Let the quantity of model $1,$ & model $2$ be denoted by $x_1,x_2$ respectively. 
The objective function is to maximize $z = 90x_1 + 150x_2.$
There are two functional constraints : $C1: 3x_1 + 2x_2 = 12,\ C2: 6x_1 + 8x_2 = 36.$ 
The extreme points of the feasible region are:
(i) $X1: (x_1=4, x_2=0),$ (ii) $X2: (x_1=2, x_2=3),$ (iii) $X3: (x_1=0, x_2=4.5).$
The pythagorean distances of the three extreme points from the origin, are:
(i) $|X1|=\sqrt{4^2} = 4,$ (ii) $|X2|=\sqrt{2^2+3^2} = \sqrt{13}= 3.6,$ (iii) $|X3|=\sqrt{4.5^2} = 4.5.$
The value of the objective function, at these three extreme points are:
(i) $z_{X1} = 90*4 = 360,$ (ii) $z_{X2} = 90*2 + 150*2 = 180+300 = 480,$ (iii) $z_{X3} = 150*4.5 = 675.$
So, this measure seems correct as the maximum distance, & also the maximum value of the objective function is at $X3=(0,4.5).$
Above all this measure seems better than the usual approach, which is actually suggested by the above source; i.e. of first finding the slope of the objective function (which applies only in the case of the objective function, being a straight line), and then slide the ruler (with the same angle of orientation, as the slope of the objective function); and find the point of contact with the feasible region, for minimization / maximization.
Also, this measure should applicable for any LPP, irrespective of the number of axes (dimensions), though that part need be proved.
Hence, request inputs for proof of the same.

It is not a valid approach. If we can decide the optimal solution based on distance from the origin, then the direction no longer matters (i.e. the objective function doesn't matter at all).
For a counterexample, let me change the objective function to maximize $x$, of which the optimal solution is at $(4,0)$.


Note that the direction  of the straight line of the objective function matters.
The source unfortunately is not a good source for learning mathematics. Their linear programming is only restricted to certain form. For example, the feasible set is a subset of the first quadrant and there are restrictions on the sign of the coefficients of the objective function.


First, am unclear how direction matters even; where I mean by direction, the next vertex of the feasible region used. Second: Even more, am naive enough still to see that the objective function, should matter as a a must, as in simplex method, i.e. $Z_j - C_j.$ I  mean why it must matter, in finding the next vertex (of the feasible region); and what is the harm in ignoring it. Seems a feasible region with few more constraints, & hence more edges, can help in understanding the two issues raised now.

recall that the graphical method, we move along the direction of the objective function. the objective function is the function that determines which solution is better, if you ignore it and just replace it with a distance function, then why bother having an objective function in the first place. In fact, for each corner, we can define an objective function such that the vertex is optimal.  If your method ignores the objective function, the method must be wrong.

Thanks, but need either some sort of proof or an example proving the same, i.e. the distance function (pythagorean distance from origin) being less is not enough.

Look at the example you tried, just change the objective function to maximize $x$. $X1$ is the optimal solution and not $X3$.

So, changing the objective function to $z= 150x_1 + 90x_2,$ would make $X_1$ as the optimal solution. But, then the slope of the iso-profit line matters (&, hence the y-intercept made by $z$ for different extreme points), for determining the optimal extreme point (at boundary of the feasible region), provided an edge of the feasible region is not parallel to $z.$ But, we all know that $X_2$ usually comes as the optimal point. But, not here? What change need be brought to the objective function (&, hence its slope), to get this usual result?

I think that the change need be made is to have a slope for the objective fn. $z,$ s.t. it straddles through the two triangular regions; where one solution is feasible, but the other is not. A slope for $z,$ i.e. more steep, or less steep than that; causes the optimum point to shift to $X_1,$ & $X_3$ respectively.

by now, we have moved beyond the scope of the original question. the slope to achieve optimality when it's between the slope of the defining edges and also the coefficient has to be positive in this special case.  Please refrain from long comment threads.
